# Why same font sizes in different viewports have weird difference?

Tags: html, css, fonts, media-queries, viewport

I have an 2 HTMLs 1st with viewport tag which is in comments 2nd is without it: `

```
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>Civil War History</title>  
 <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> it is in the first -->
   <link href="cssfile.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
  <div> Large Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
     consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores
     at deleniti exercitationem expedita laboriosam
     laborum laudantium tempora ullam.
     Delectus deserunt ducimus error esse
     incidunt minus necessitatibus nihil,
     obcaecati quaerat recusandae?
</div>
</body>
</html>`
```

cssfile for that htmls are same (no changes):

```
div {
font-size :16px;
}
```

When i checked it in Iphone X 's viewport both of them weird behaviour. First with viewport tag has 375px dimensions with 16px font size have more words than Second one without viewport tag which has an 980 px wide and 16 px for font size . How come ?
Is not it The bigger the space the more the words ? Please explain what is happening . Thanks in  advance)

Answer (score 0):

Browsers use text inflation algorithm which causes this effect . This algorithm by default enlarges text font size when it is too small and in touchable anchors in some small width devices.

To prevent this use: `-webkit-text-size-adjustment: 100%;`.

Comment: Interesting.  Do you have a reference for this information?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket yes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust check this